# Hibernate. how to associate object with database values?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have:

```
class Candidate {

    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "candidate_vacancy", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_id"))
    List<Vacancy> list;
//get and set methods
}
```

In html form I write :

```
<form action="saveCandidate">
  name: <input type="text" value="${candidate.name}" name="name" />
type="submit" value="save changes" />
```

In @Controller I write this code:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCandidate")
    public String saveCandidate(Model model, @ModelAttribute Candidate candidate) {
        candidateService.update(candidate);
        return "candidateMenu";
    }
```

But if when I update Candidate objects, appropriate vacancies become null in Database.

I think I can manually load vacancies from db, attach its to candidate and update, But I think is more right way!

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, there shouldn't be any direct relationship between `Candidate` and `Vacancy`. As I understand it, the relation is more based on a query or, even more, on some business rule applied over a query.

So I would have a `List<Vacancy> getVacancies(Candidate candidate)` method in my service/DAO instead of a DB relationship. When implementing that method, invoke Hibernate to execute the query needed and, if needed, apply any business rule. You'll always have an updated list of vacancies for the specified user that way.

Otherwise, as you have already seen, anytime you add a new `Candidate` or `Vacancy` you will need to manually add the relationship between the two. This has nothing to do with Hibernate but more how relational databases work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use domain object in this situation as a target for binding due to following reasons:

1. You need to fetch all relations for existed object (or they will be removed as in your case)
2. This is potentially an security issue. I can change your form in browser, add some input field and update some other fields in your database.

You can use special DTO object (say `CandidateForm` that will correspond to your html form fields):

```
<form action="saveCandidate">
  <input type="hidden" value="${candidate.id}" name="id" />
  name: <input type="text" value="${candidate.name}" name="name" />

@RequestMapping("/saveCandidate")
public String saveCandidate(Model model, @ModelAttribute CandidateForm candidateForm) {
    Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
    if(candidateForm.getId() != null) {
       candidate = candidateService.getById(candidateForm.getId());
       // load existed object with relations, so they will be not removed
    }
    copyFieldsFromDtoToDomainObject(candidateForm, candidate);
    candidateService.update(candidate); // I supose that this is actually saveOrUpdate
    return "candidateMenu";
}
```

Where `id` is a primary key.

Comment: I know about it. But there 2 access to db. I think it is so bad.

Comment: It is a downside of ORM (you change DB using objects and to edit something you need to load data and prepare a object first). In some other cases you can reduce the problem by using `session.load()` instead of `session.get()` (imagine that you know ids of all `Vacancy` objects, so you can load their proxies and use during update). In your case if you want only one hit to DB then you need to drop Hibernate and use plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your object with help of special method, located in your JavaBean:

```
class Candidate {

    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "candidate_vacancy", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_id"))
    List<Vacancy> list;
    //get and set methods

    public Candidate updatePublicInfo(Candidate newCandidate) {
        this.name = newCandidate.getName();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Than in your service do:

```
class CandidateServiceImpl implements CandidateService {

    // other methods

    public void update(Candidate candidate) {
        Candidate oldCandidate = candidateDao.findById(candidate.getId());
        oldCandidate.updatePublicInfo(candidate);
        candidateDao.save(oldCandidate);
    }
}
```

Comment: quote: "This approach does not clutter the service layer with domain logic and and ensures that you do not end up with an anemic domain model". Source: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/